# pandas data frame sort

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this which I try to sort by column 'dist'. The sorted dataframe should start with E or F as per below. I use sort_values which it is not working for me. The function is computing distances from 'Start' location to a list of locations ['C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'F'] and then is supposed to sort the dataframe in ascending order using 'dist' column.
Could someone advice me why sorting is not working?

```
locations = {'Start':(20,5),'A':(10,3), 'B':(5,3), 'C':(5, 7), 'D':(10,7),'E':(14,4),'F':(14,6)}

    loc_list
Out[194]: ['C', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'F']

def closest_locations(from_loc_point, to_loc_list):
    lresults=list()
    for list_index in range(len(to_loc_list)):
        dist= hypot(locations[from_loc_point[0]][0] -locations[to_loc_list[list_index]][0],locations[from_loc_point[0]][1] -locations[to_loc_list[list_index]][1]) # cumsum distante
        lista_dist = [from_loc_point[0],to_loc_list[list_index],dist]
        lresults.append(lista_dist[:])
    RESULTS = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lresults))
    RESULTS.columns = ['from','to','dist']
    RESULTS.sort_values(['dist'],ascending=[True],inplace=True)
    RESULTS.index = range(len(RESULTS))
    return RESULTS

closest_locations(['Start'], loc_list)
Out[189]: 
    from to                dist
0  Start  D   10.19803902718557
1  Start  A   10.19803902718557
2  Start  C  15.132745950421555
3  Start  B  15.132745950421555
4  Start  E    6.08276253029822
5  Start  F    6.08276253029822
```

closest_two_loc.dtypes
Out[247]:

```
from    object
to      object
dist    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: What is `hypot` function?

Comment: I use hypot to compute the distance between two points using their coordinates. This part is working fine and I obtain the table of distances which I posted already. My problem is that I cannot sort it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html (math.hypot(x, y)
Return the Euclidean norm, sqrt(x*x + y*y). This is the length of the vector from the origin to point (x, y).)

Comment: The only option I can see that explains what is happening is that the entries in the dist column are strings and not floats. Can you check if type(Results["dist"].iloc[0]) returns a string or a float?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
locations = {'Start':(20,5),'A':(10,3), 'B':(5,3), 'C':(5, 7), 'D':(10,7),'E':(14,4),'F':(14,6)}
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(locations, orient='index').rename(columns={0:'x', 1:'y'})
df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.np.sqrt((row['x'] - df.loc['Start', 'x'])**2 + (row['y'] - df.loc['Start', 'y'])**2), axis=1)
df.drop(['Start']).sort_values(by='dist')
    x  y       dist
E  14  4   6.082763
F  14  6   6.082763
A  10  3  10.198039
D  10  7  10.198039
C   5  7  15.132746
B   5  3  15.132746
```

or if you want to wrap it in a function

```
def dist_from(df, col):
    df['dist'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.np.sqrt((row['x'] - df.loc[col,'x'])**2 + (row['y'] - df.loc[col, 'y'])**2), axis=1)
    df['form'] = col
    df.drop([col]).sort_values(by='dist')
    df.index.name = 'to'
    return df.reset_index().loc[:, ['from', 'to', 'dist']]
```

Comment: Not sure. I have already the resulting dataframe: 'closest_locations'. My questions is why sorting is not working as described? 
closest_two_loc.sort_values(by='dist',ascending=True,inplace=True)

Comment: print out the dtypes of the dataframe. Sometimes the values might not be a float

>>df.dtypes

and post the results

Comment: closest_two_loc.dtypes
Out[247]: 
from    object
to      object
dist    object
dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert values in "dist" column to float:

```
df = closest_locations(['Start'], loc_list)
df.dist = list(map(lambda x: float(x), df.dist)) # convert each value to float
print(df.sort_values('dist'))                    # now it will sort properly
```

Output:

```
    from to       dist
4  Start  E   6.082763
5  Start  F   6.082763
0  Start  D  10.198039
1  Start  A  10.198039
2  Start  C  15.132746
3  Start  B  15.132746
```

Edit: As mentioned by @jezrael in comments, following is a more direct method:

```
df.dist = df.dist.astype(float)
```

Comment: Nice, only better is use `df.dist = df.dist.astype(float)`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the dtype issue. I resolved the problem adding this one line in my function: RESULTS['dist']= RESULTS['dist'].apply(pd.to_numeric)

Comment: In that case, you should upvote/accept this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
 ).